# Xdebug and Netbeans not collaborating: No connection from xdebug was detected

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I've just installed xdebug and netbeans on my ubuntu 11.10.
I'd like to use xdebug but even if I paste my php info in the xdebug page (http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php) and it says "You're already running the latest Xdebug version" when I try to debug from Netbeans I get the "No connection from xdebug was detected" error.

In Netbeans options I have port 9000 and in my xdebug.ini I have:

`zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"`

`xdebug.remote_enable=on`

`xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp`

`xdebug.remote_host=localhost`

`xdebug.remote_port=9000`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is port 9000 opened on firewall?

Comment: Ubuntu's firewall is disabled by default... I've disabled it again (sudo ufw disable) to be sure but it wasn't helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it helps, but I have one line different and one more line:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

There's a small HowTo http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Answer (score 0):

Running the latest version might not be the best option in this case. Have you checked if your version of PHP is compatible with the latest version of xdebug? You could try the wizard on the xdebug.org site [link](http://www.xdebug.org/wizard.php). Futhermore, you could add xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug tot the php.ini file.

Comment: I don't know if you still have the same problem, but I have got xdebug / netbeans running after setting the port in netbeans to 9001 and xdebug to 9000. For some strange reason everything now works.
You could also configure xdebug.ini instead of php.ini.